# aapt dump not producing the output needed

Tags: android, windows, aapt

Hey all I am trying to figure out why the following command does not produce the needed output:

```
aapt dump badging c:/adb/apks/ftp/ftp.apk " | sed -r s/package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*/\1/"
```

This just produces a lot of text:

```
package: name='com.medhaapps.wififtpserver' versionCode='74' versionName='1.9.5' compileSdkVersion='28' compileSdkVersionCodename='9'
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'28'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE'
uses-permission-sdk-23: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
application-label:'WiFi FTP Server'
......ETC ETC.....
```

Shouldn't this just produce:

```
package: name='com.medhaapps.wififtpserver'
```

Comment: @Robert If I don't add those quotes then I get the error: `'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Robert Yep that worked. Please provide that as an official answer so I can give you credit and help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aapt dump badging c:/adb/apks/ftp/ftp.apk " | sed -r s/package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*/\1/"
```

The command you were trying to use has two problems:

1. You added double quotes around the second part of the command, which changes the command.
2. You are on Windows and the command is designed to be executed on Linux.

The original working command without quotes is

```
aapt dump badging c:/adb/apks/ftp/ftp.apk  | sed -r s/package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*/\1/
```

It combines the two programs `aapt` from Android SDK and the standard Linux tool **S**tream **ED**itor `sed`. As you are on Windows this command is not available by default.

The easiest way to get a Windows version of `sed` is install the version tool GIT CSM (the official open source version). It provides several Windows versions of standard Linux programs like `sed`. On a standard installation you will sind an `sed.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`. So just append that directory to your `PATH` and you will have a working `sed` version ready for the command.